# Xcode compiler flag to draw view edges

Tags: xcode, debugging, uiview, autolayout

I'm working with Auto Layout in code and I am unsure where some edges are falling. I know there is a way to draw yellow lines for all view edges, but I can't find it.

Does anyone here know compiler flag/build environment variable that can be set to draw an outline for all views, or point me to a reference that contains this?

Comment: Suggestion: Get either [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com) (no code modifications are needed) or [Reveal](http://revealapp.com) (code changes or LLDB additions). They will allow you to inspect all views and their hierarchy and make changes while the app is running. Must have and there are free trials.

Answer (score 1):

Run the app in Xcode, then go to menu Debug/View Debugging/Show View Frames. This setting doesn't appear to be sticky, so each time you run, you'll have to do it again.

You can also do similar with Quartz Debug under the tools menu. But it affects all apps, not just the one you are debugging. And Quartz Debug no longer ships as standard with XCode. Might be available for download if you don't already have it.

Comment: Hey @Steve, the menu for Debug/View Debugging/Show View Frames is always grayed out for me. Whether simulator is running, or I've paused the app. The menu is never in a state where i can select it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't realise you were doing iOS. These options are for OSX debugging. Suggest going with Zaph's suggestion. Those apps look great.

Comment: I think it only works for iOS 8 and up. Any ideas to make this sticky though?

Answer (score 1):

Since you were enquiring about the Xcode argument, here it is:
`-UIViewShowAlignmentRects YES`. Add this to your scheme's "Arguments Passed on Launch".

Beware that this seems to crash some apps on iOS 11 and Apple is aware of it.

Comment: Still seeing an exception when setting that flag in iOS 14.2.

Comment: same problem , how to fix it